# Endomorphism Conjugacy classes and the structure theorem for $k[x]$-vector spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $S$ and $T$ be endomorphisms on the $k$ finite-dimensional vector space $V$, where $k$ is a field. Then,

> $\textbf{Theorem:}$
> The $k[x]$-modules optioned from $V$ via $S$ and via $T$ are isomorphic if and only if $S=gTg^{-1}$ for some automorphism $g: V \to V$.

From the structure theorem we have that,

> $V_S \cong k[x] / ((a(x)) \oplus \dots \oplus k[x] / (a_m(x))$
>
> $V_T \cong k[x] / ((b(x)) \oplus \dots \oplus k[x] / (b_n(x))$

And so if $S$ and $T$ are similar we have that,

> $k[x] / ((a(x)) \oplus \dots \oplus k[x] / (a_m(x))$ $\cong k[x] / ((b(x)) \oplus \dots \oplus k[x] / (b_n(x))$

My notes go on to state that this implies that there is a bijection between choice of invariant factors and the conjugacy classes of the endomorphisms. I am trying to reason through this statement as follows,

I know the rational canonical forms (completely dependent on the choice of invariant factors) of the matrices $S$ and $T$ will be the same, so does this imply that $(a_i(x)) = (b_j(x))$? In which case, every conjugacy class would give us one choice of invariant factors.

Comment: As you say, by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain, the $a_i(x)$ are unique, up to unit. But it seems to me the statement of the theorem is a quasi tautology. The ring $k[x]$ is a free $k$ algebra wiith $x$ as generator. So the two $k[x]$ structures on $V$ give rise to isomorphic modules $k[x]$-modules if and only if there is a $k$-linear invertible $g$ of $V$ such that $x \cdot g = g \cdot x$, where one of the $x$ acts as $S$, and the other acts as $T$. Am I missing something here?